# What resources exist for a ger toshav?

Tags: product-recommendation, ger-toshav

I am trying to observe the 7 Noahide commandments, as a ger toshav. However, I am struggling to find resources that apply to a ger toshav and can only find resources that apply to Jews. What resources should I look for and to what extent are resources for Jews applicable?

Comment: Are you aware that the mainstream view nowadays in Judaism is that it is currently impossible to attain the status of Get Toshav? You may be having trouble finding resources because there isn't a target audience

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, I am.

Comment: @user16 so why do you expect any resources? This seems like a silly question

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "get toshav"?

Comment: I have heard good and bad things about [this book](https://www.amazon.com/World-Ger-Chaim-Clorfene/dp/1530655684).

Comment: @ClintEastwood its "ger" not "get". it refers to a gentile that keeps the 7 mitzvos.

Comment: In that case, that is a regular Noahide.

Comment: @ClintEastwood - A Ger Toshav was a type of Ben Noach that existed back when the First Temple was standing. The position does not exist anymore, because of the Temple's destruction. I don't have enough room to explain what a ger toshav is, so here's a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ger_toshav

Comment: I know what it is, but he defined it as a regular Noahide

Comment: If I remember right, Ger Toshav is a condition under which a gentile is allowed to dwell in the Promised Land under Jewish rule (as otherwise, we're obligated to kill all other gentiles, who are considered idolaters by default). This can only apply under a Jewish King, when we're allowed to openly judge gentiles. So till the days of the Moshiah, this is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

In the same way that Jews are preparing for the coming of Mashiach (e.g., in learning the laws of the temple and of sacrifices which are not yet re-activated), non-Jews should learn the Noahide laws.

I am aware of two quality books that can help non-Jews do so

- The Path of the Righteous Gentile: An Introduction to the Seven Laws of the Children of Noah by Chaim Clorfene  and Yaakov Rogalsky ([amazon](http://a.co/9G7g7zR))
- Sefer Sheva Mitzvot HaShem by R Moshe Weiner, in English: The Divine Code ([here](https://asknoah.org/books/the-divine-code)), see also [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87743/11501) on MY regarding approbations

In addition, see the [website](https://noahideworldcenter.org/wp_en/) of Brit Olam, the Noahide World Center.