# Is the "Sefer Sheva Mitzvot HaShem" by Rabbi Moshe Weiner an authoritative legal code for the Noahides?

Tags: jewish-books, noachide-laws, authority

I am an Italian gentile believer in HaShem, who engages in the observance of the Noahide Precepts, as commanded by the Creator in the Torah.

Unfortunately, there is no Halachic study in the Italian language for the sons of Noah; it is a very serious absence, because we Noahides need a legal code like, for example, the Mishneh Torah for the Jews, that explains in detail the precepts that HaShem has commanded us to observe; Rabbi Aharon Lichtenstein wrote a book like this years ago, but unfortunately the Italian edition is now unobtainable.
Recently I read the following news on Wikipedia:

> In 2005, Rabbi Moshe Weiner of Jerusalem accepted to produce an
>   in-depth codification of the Noahide precepts.The work is called Sefer
>   Sheva Mitzvot HaShem, (The Book of Seven Divine Commandments)
>   published 2008/2009. As it was approved by both of the then presiding
>   chief rabbis of Israel (Rabbi Shlomo Moshe Amar and Rabbi Yonah
>   Metzger) as well as by other Hasidic and non-Hasidic halachic
>   authorities, it can claim an authoritative character and is referred
>   as a Shulchan Aruch for Gentiles at many places.

Since my confidence in Wikipedia is rather limited, I ask you to confirm if this legal code is really so authoritative; If so, it is my wish to involve the Union of Italian Jewish Communities to sponsor a translation of the text in Italian, in the meantime I will recover the English version, even if my English is not exactly brilliant

Comment: That Mishnah Torah you mentioned does address laws for non-Jews in Laws of Kings and Wars chapters 9-10. Before anyone votes to close, while the motivation for this question is practical, the question itself is not on Halacha and therefore should not be closed as practical Halacha. That said, I do think you should track down a Rabbi in your area to discuss these laws with him. Good luck in your quest, and may you have much success.

Comment: [Rabbi Uri Sherki](http://ravsherki.org) is in the process of writing such a legal code. I suggest contacting the Rabbi directly or his organization dedicated to helping Noahides, ["Brit Olam"](http://www.en.noahideworldcenter.org/). They have recently published a prayerbook for Noahides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[asknoah.org](https://asknoah.org/) sponsored the book you mention. [They write that](https://asknoah.org/books/sheva-mitzvot-hashem)

> Sheva Mitzvot HaShem was submitted for review by the world-renowned
>   rabbinic authority, Haga’on Rav Zalman Nechemiah Goldberg shlit”a,
>   member of the Supreme Rabbinical Court of Israel, who examined the
>   full text in detail, added comments in many of the footnotes, and
>   granted his approbation.
>
> The set also enjoys approbations from a Chief
>   Rabbis of Israel, Rav Shlomo Moshe Amar; Rav Yakov Y. Eliezrov, Head
>   of the Rabbinical Court of Greater Jerusalem; Rav Gedalia Dov
>   Schwartz, Av Beit Din for both the Chicago Rabbinical Council (CRC)
>   and the Rabbinical Council of America (RCA); and Rav Jacob Immanuel
>   Schochet o.b.m. of Toronto, Canada.

All the rabbis mentioned above are impeccable rabbis, known for their deep Torah knowledge. Someone would have to check if indeed the book has their approbations (typically a letter at the beginning of the book). The approbation from R Shlomo Amar (the Sefardi Chief Rabbi of Israel) is actually online [here](https://asknoah.org/wp-content/uploads/Rabbi_Amar_letter_of_blessing.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand Rabbi Moshe Weiner is bona fide orthodox Jewish rabbi, and I think the book is widely considered accurate, although calling it the Shulchan Aruch for Gentiles is hyperbole. I should point out certain rabbis oppose the publication of halachic works for Noahides.

Comment: I’m not sure why anyone would oppose such works. If it’s an issue of learning Torah, non-Jews are allowed - nay, encouraged - to learn the Torah which applies to them.

Comment: @DonielF also, I believe (but don't have a reference in front of me) that Torah learning for Gentiles is only strictly forbidden for *idolaters*, so a Noachide would, in theory, be permitted to learn the entire Torah.

Comment: @RobertColumbia The Gemara is in Sanhedrin 59a. Although it does use the term עובד כוכבים, given the reasons of אל תקרי מורשה אלא מאורסה or גזילה there’s no reason to differentiate between an idolater and an ordinary non-Jew. Especially in the uncensored Gemaros, עובד כוכבים was the standard term for all non-Jews, since most, if not all, of the non-Jews in the area were idolaters (pagan Romans).